# luatodonotes package: note appears in Todo list, but not shown in the text

Tags: luatex, todonotes

Using LuaLaTeX and the `luatodonotes` package, I can't see any of the notes I added by `\todo{}`. Nevertheless they are shown in the Todo list. Other features of the package, like the `\missingfigure{}`, are working.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{test}
\missingfigure{sketch of ...}
\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the example compile without errors for you? I get `/luatodonotes.lua:2117: Cannot place labels on any side of text (not enough space). Consider using the additionalMargin option of the package to extend the page margins or minNoteWidth to decrease the minimum width required`. And indeed with a slightly different margin setting for example `\documentclass[12pt, DIV=10]{scrreprt}` the example compiles fine for me and the todonote test appears on the left or the page.

Comment: Yes, this code is compiling without errors for me. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this.

Comment: Note that changing the `DIV` settings will have a serious effect on the overall design of your document. The margins and text sizes will be different. It was just the quickest way for me to make enough room for the note.

Answer (score 2):

Do as the error message (and the documentation) says: decrease the minimal width of the notes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[minNoteWidth=1.5cm]{luatodonotes}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{test}
\missingfigure{sketch of ...}
\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

[image]